# Fazer busca em array usando mais de uma palavra

Tags: php, array

Quero fazer busca em um `array` e usar mais de uma palavra, o problema esta no fato de que quero que ele só me retorne algo se existir todas as palavras no `array` e não apenas uma, estou fazendo da seguinte forma mas não esta dando certo:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['palavra'])):

    $palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
    $separa  = explode(' ', $palavra);

    if(in_array(array("você", "bem", "?"), $separa)):
        echo "Bem e você ?";
    endif;

endif;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez você consiga com algo assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['palavra'])):


    $palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
    $separa  = explode(' ', $palavra);

    $palavrasChaves = array("você", "bem", "?");

    $quaisContem = array_intersect($separa, $palavrasChaves);

    sort($palavrasChaves);
    sort($quaisContem);

    if($quaisContem === $palavrasChaves):
        echo "Bem e você ?";
    endif;


endif;
```

Utilizei `array_intersect` para verificar quais palavras do segundo `array` são encontrados no primeiro. Assim, ele retorna quais são valores encontrados no primeiro array, que estão no segundo. Aplico um `sort` nos dois, para a ordenação ficar similar. Em seguida comparo os dois com `===`. Se for verdadeiro, é porque todas as palavras procuradas estão na lista que você separou.

Para que você possa entenda um pouco sobre `array_intersect`, farei uns exemplos:

```
array_intersect(['a', 'b'], ['a']); // ['a']

array_intersect(['a'], ['a', 'b']); // ['a'] ('a' presente no segundo está no primeiro
```

Comment: deu certinho, então a diferença do array_intersect e do in_array é que um busca apenas uma string em um array, e a outra faz buscas de um array dentro de outro ne ?

Comment: Bom uso do `array_intersect`. Por que não é feita a comparação usando `==`? assim o `sort` talvez não seja necessário.

Comment: @stderr seria necessário ainda...

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra alternativa é a função [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php), você pode implementá-la assim <sup>([créditos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040612/1608936))</sup>:

```
function in_array_all($needles, $haystack) {
   return !array_diff($needles, $haystack);
}
```

O `array_diff` retorna um `array` com todos os valores de `$needles` que **não** aparecem em `$haystack`, para inverter o resultado é usado o [operador de negação lógica `!`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1k6w8551.aspx).

Use assim:

```
$palavrasChaves = ["você", "bem", "?"];

if (isset($_POST['palavra']) && $palavra = $_POST['palavra']) {
    $pedacos  = explode(' ', $palavra);

    if (in_array_all($palavrasChaves, $pedacos)) {
        echo "Bem e você ?";
    } else {
        echo "Não estou bem.";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/C9SvlJ)</kbd>